# Combobox itemssource and selecteditem synchronization

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a combobox that is bound to `ObservableCollection<Item>` in the ViewModel. When a user adds a new item I don't know if they've added an item to the bound collection so I do a refresh. Well this sets the selecteditem to null so I implemented some code to remember the selected item and set it after the Collection is renewed. The problem is the collection doesn't display the selecteditem.

```
if (_selectedBrand != null)
{
    int selectedBrandID = _selectedBrand.BrandID;
    Brands = null;
    Brands = new ObservableCollection<Brand>(_dataContext.Brands.ToList());
    SelectedBrand = _dataContext.Brands.First<Brand>(b => b.BrandID == selectedBrandID);
}
```

How can I get the collection to display the corrected item?

**Edit:** The collection represents a table in the backend DB. The user can open a new window to add items to the DB. Once the window is closed I must refresh the collection to get any new items. Sorry for the confusion of my wording.

Comment: Normally the `ObservableCollection<T>` should notify that an item was added. How do you let the user add an item?

Comment: "When a user adds a new item I don't know if they've added an item to the bound collection so I do a refresh": seems strange to me that user adds something to yuor model and you don't know, if so, what is all this binding about ?

Comment: Yes adding an item to ObservableCollection raises an event, so you should be able to subscribe to that event and handle it.

Comment: I'll edit my original question... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you not just retrieve the new collection, and then update the existing one adding in the missing values (using the linq extension except?)

Comment: @Bob - This is the first time I used except and it works quite well... Thanks. How can I mark this comment as the accepted answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just retrieve the new collection, and then update the existing one adding in the missing values (using the linq extension except?)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your `SelectedBrand` to an item in your `_dataContext.Brands`, which doesn't exist in the `Brands` ObservableCollection.

Change your code to set `SelectedBrand` to an item in your `ObservableCollection`, not your `_dataContext`.

```
SelectedBrand = Brands.First<Brand>(b => b.BrandID == selectedBrandID);
```

Comment: That works for the search but now the view doesn't show the brand properly... it shows nothing. Should I set Brands to null first or just re-initialize it.

Comment: @John Does the `Brands` and `SelectedBrand` properties both raise a PropertyChange notification?

Comment: @John The code you posted works fine for me. I'm assuming you have the ComboBox's `SelectedItem` bound to `SelectedBrand`? Put a breakpoint in your code as well and make sure that the SelectedBrand is getting set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this code is in the context of a Button Click eventhandler? So I'm not sure why you are havign to reinitialize the collection everytime. You should be able to just use the Brands.Add method. I don't have .net 3.5 at my workplace so I'll just have to psuedo code it.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but maybe it can help.

```
public sealed partial class ObservableCollectionExample : Form
{

private ObservableCollectionExample()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}

private ObservableCollectionExample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Subscribe to the collection changed event
      Brands.CollectionChanged += new EventArgs<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>(Brands_Changed);
}

private Brands_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Add code to do something when the Brands collection is changed i.e. something is added or removed via the .Add or .Remove method
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (_selectedBrand != null)
     {
          Brands.Add(foobar);
          if (_dataContext.Brands.First<Brand>(b => b.BrandID == selectedBrandID)) // Do some checking to see if it got added to the collection
          {
          SelectedBrand = _selectedBrand.BrandId;
          }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm using the MVVM pattern. The user clicks a button which opens a window and has the option to add new Brands in that window. Once the window closes the main window with the combobox has no idea if a new brand was added or not.